# Is a host OS more vulnerable to a hypervisor escape if the guest OS knows the root password to the host?

Tags: password-management, isolation

This is assuming that escaping the hypervisor is the only way the guest OS could compromise the host-- e.g. it's not networked, isn't sharing folders or the clipboard, etc. Does knowledge about the host's root password matter in the context of maintaining isolation through a (type one or two) hypervisor?

Comment: I don't think this will help you to beak out under this assumptions, but if you escaped you could escalate privileges easy

Comment: @trietend I agree with your assumption, but note that AFAIK hypervisors need elevated privileges to be able to administrate the virtual resources. It's unlikely that if the attacker escapes the hypervisor context he won't have those privileges

Comment: @Mr.E Not necessarily true. A hypervisor usually has two components. One of them is privileged and manages VT-x (for example KVM). The other emulates hardware drivers and communicates with the former through its API (for example QEMU). It's this latter component which has the largest attack surface area and, thankfully, can unprivileged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In order to use the root password, the hypervisor must first be escaped.**

The root password is only used by userspace applications to request greater permissions. The way a root password works is simple. When an application wants to switch to a more privileged user, a trusted and privileged program reads the password, hashes it, and compares the hash against the stored password hash in `/etc/shadow`. If the password matches, this trusted program executes the application as root. This is why the root password is considered sensitive.

In order to (ab)use the root password, a malicious application needs to be able to perform *syscalls*, the primary API between userspace and the kernel. To use the `su` program to elevate privileges for example, the `execve()` and `read()` syscalls are needed to run the program and pass the root password to it, respectively. A guest operating system running in a hypervisor does not have access to syscalls on the host, only to the hypervisor itself (using so-called *hypercalls*), and to the kernel which is running virtualized. In order to escape from the hypervisor, a bug in its programming must be exploited. Knowledge of the host's root password thus does not help escape a hypervisor because it can only be used to elevate privileges *after* the hypervisor has already been broken!

While knowledge of the root password does not make a hypervisor escape easier, it is still not necessarily a good idea to give it to the guest. If the hypervisor is running unprivileged but is not sandboxed (e.g. QEMU with sandboxing disabled), a hypervisor escape may allow the attacker to run with the privileges of the hypervisor software. If they know the root password, they may use it to elevate privileges *after* they have broken out of the hypervisor.

Comment: For `sudo` you don't need the root password. To use `sudo`, you have to enter the password of the user u are currently executing the command. You can escalate privileges using `su` with the root password.-

Comment: @trietend You can also use the root password, depending on what arguments you send to `sudo` (you can only use your own password if you are in the wheel group or an equivalent). But you are right, `su` is probably a better example. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With no other connectivity to the host (or the outside world), that shouldn't be enough to break out by itself. It's still a bad idea, though; if the malicious VM breaks out with only limited privileges on the host, it could use the root password to elevate its privileges. (Why would you want it to know that password anyhow?).

---

Not relevant to your question, but just to be clear:

Having *any* password for the host might allow a VM to escape if it can, for example, SSH into the host (and having the root password would either allow it to SSH straight to root or, if that is disabled the way it usually is, upgrade privileges to root after getting in as some other user). Using any other remote session (RDP, VNC, NoMachine, etc.) or remote management (DCOM/RPC, Group Policy, Puppet, etc.) frameworks would also give the hostile VM an avenue to escape the hypervisor, assuming it has the relevant credentials and can connect to the relevant machine (usually but not always the host OS) on the relevant port(s).